# Why is this loop stopping after the first pass?

Tags: excel, vba

I want my function to loop over a set number of times before it gives me an answer. It's stopping after the first loop. I want it to go through the loop "PerInq" times before giving me the answer. I have a series of math problems that must done consecutively to get the proper answer. Below is my code:

```
Function IntFinder(PVLoan, APR, PMT_Freq, Term, PerInq)
n = PMT_Freq * Term
R = APR / PMT_Freq
PMT1 = Pmt(R, n, -PVLoan)
Intrest = PVLoan * R
Prin = PMT1 - Intrest
Bal = PVLoan - Prin
BalSum = 0
For counter = 1 To counter = PerInq
    Intrest = R * Bal
    Prin = PMT1 - Intrest
    Bal = Bal - Prin
    counter = counter + 1
Next counter
IntFinder = Intrest
End Function
```

Comment: Change `For counter = 1 To counter = PerInq` to `For counter = 1 To PerInq`. But why do you have `counter = counter + 1`? Do you want to take steps of 2? Because `Next counter` will autoincrease by 1. If you do want to step 2, then `For counter = 1 To PerInq Step 2` will do.

Comment: @JvdV IT WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Please do not yell at the volunteers. They are easily spooked ;)